# Diferencia entre @WebServlet("/") y @WebServlet("/*")

Tags: java, servlets

Al crear un `servlet`, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre usar los siguientes patrones para definir la URL? `"/"` y `"/*"`, usando anotaciones y la especificación 3.1.

```
@WebServlet("/")

@WebServlet("/*")
```

¿Cuál de estos patrones de URL debo usar si deseo que mi servlet responda a cualquier petición?
¿Son iguales o existe alguna diferencia entre ellos?

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia es que `@WebServlet("/")` sólo va a responder a algo como `unaweb.com` o `unaweb.com/`.

Mientras que `@WebServlet("/*")` va a responder a

- `unaweb.com/paginauno`
- `unaweb.com/unapagina`
- `unaweb.com/ndjdjd`

En resumen puedes poner la cadena que sea después de la diagonal.

Así que su quieres que responda a cualquier patrón usa la segunda opción.

Comment: Yo añadiría como ejemplo `unaweb.com/una/carpeta/y/ahora/mi/pagina.html`. Además que el servlet tb atendería cosas como URLs de recursos (archivos js, css, imágenes, etc)